VSCode not finding libraries which were installed with MSYS2
I have the following Problem: When I open my project in VSCode only the cjson/cJson.h library is not found
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <cjson/cJSON.h>  //this one is not found

This is my current compiler path in the C/C++ extension configuration: C:\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
I installed a new library using this command in MSYS2 exe : pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cjson
I found the installed new library here: C:\msys64\mingw64\include\cjson\
cJson.h and cJson.utils.h
Do I maybe have 2 installations of mingw64 and i am using the wrong one?
or do I have to somehow add mingw64 from the MSYS2 folder into the compiler path?
I unfortunatly can't find out what the problem here is.
